# Why is the post request not working in gin golang?

Tags: go, post, go-gin

This code does not work, the response will be empty, like this `{"test":""}`.

```
    func main() {
            router := gin.Default()

            router.POST("/test", f

unc(c *gin.Context) {
            test := c.Query("test")
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "test": test,
            })
        })
        router.Run()
    }
```

UPDATED:
I found the simple solution via struct:

```
func test(c *gin.Context) {
    test := struct {
        Test   string `json:"test"`
        Test2 string `json:"test2"`
    }{}
    c.BindJSON(&test)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "test1":  test.Test,
        "test2": test.Test2,
    })
}
```

Comment: You didn't pass a query string parameter `test`, so it's empty.

Comment: @Adrian , no, I passed, the problem in gin I think, maybe I will change the gin to another library.

Comment: In your screenshot, there is no query string at all.

Comment: @Adrian, well, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func test(c *gin.Context) {
    test := struct {
        Test   string `json:"test"`
        Test2 string `json:"test2"`
    }{}
    c.BindJSON(&test)

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "test1":  test.Test,
        "test2": test.Test2,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data as body, you should bind the body to a variable to have access to it.

```
type Data struct {
   test string
}
// ...

router.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
   var data Data        
   c.BindJSON(&data)

   c.JSON(200, gin.H{ 
      "test": data.test,
   })
})
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand how to use it, it doesn't work for me again. Can I send json requests like this {"data":"data123"}?

Comment: your JSON request should follow the struct created to hold the data, in this case it should be {"test": "data123"}

Comment: I don't know why, but it is not working. The response is still {"test":""}

Comment: I found a solution

Comment: that's great news! what was the issue?

Comment: Your solution is almost right, but you should use `Test string` in the struct, not the  `test string`.